# What is the difference between these two string statements?

Tags: c++, string

What is the difference between these two statements?

```
    #include <string>    

    string str = "hello";
    
    // and
    
    string str2 = string("hello");
```

Comment: As of C++ 17, not much. Before that the class had to be copyable for `string str2 = string("hello");` to be allowed. [Here's some good documentation on the different types of initialization in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

Comment: [If you want to go deeper, here's a good presentation on the topic of initialization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs).

Comment: In the first statement, the `std::string` constructor is called that converts a constant string literal into a `std::string`.  The second statement creates a temporary `std::string` object and assigns to `str2`.  The compiler is usually smart enough to consider statement 2 as an initialization and may not create the temporary object.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews by object do you mean as an instance of a class?

Comment: Oxford Dictionary says an instance is *an example or single occurrence of something*.  In object oriented programming an object is an instance, a single occurrence, of a class. In C++ sometimes you need to be more precise and use the term instance rather than object because C++ derives from C and has [a much broader definition of object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews what you describe is what happened before C++17.  But in C++17 onward, no temporary is created anymore, `string str2 = string("hello");` is treated *identical* to `string str2("hello");` which is how `string str = "hello";` is also treated, thus the two statements are effectively identical in modern C++.

Comment: Note that both examples are inferior to using the `std::string` literal format, `std::string str = "hello"s;` or equivalently (since you're using the literal that enforces the correct type) `auto str = "hello"s;`. Both versions mean the string can be constructed using the two-arg form of initialization (pointer to data and compile-time known length) rather than the "from C-style string" method (which doesn't allow embedded `NUL`s, and typically scans the string at runtime to determine the length so it knows how much to allocate). Just need C++14 and `using namespace std::literals;`.